# What is the word for the way someone is speaking to you like this?

Tags: word-choice

The subject of the conversation is sensitive and controversial and the adult child of the other person is very passionate and being preachy says something like “You know that’s blank blank?  I hope you appreciate blank blank.” What is the word to describe the way in which the adult child is speaking to their parent? This could be between any two people.  This is just the actual situation that just occurred.

Comment: Impossible to say without more context.

Comment: "You know that's Fred Mertz?  I hope you appreciate Fred Mertz, because he's the one who shoveled your walk last winter."

Comment: It depends on what *blank blank* stands for (it could be different in each instance), the emotional attitude of the person talking, the intonation they are using, and what they're trying to convey. It's also not clear why the fact that it's an adult child speaking to their parent is relevant …

Comment: I only put the adult and child part because that is the context  of the actual situation but yes, it doesn’t matter.